# Get multiple numbers from a string

Tags: c#, wpf, string, numbers

I have strings like

> AS_!SD 2453iur ks@d9304-52kasd

I need to get the 2 frist numbres of the string:

for that case will be:
`2453` and `9304`

I don't have any delimiter in the string to try a split, and the length of the numbers and string is variable, I'm working in C# framework 4.0 in a WPF.

thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Use the regular expression `\d{4}` and take the first  matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution will take two first numbers, each can have any number of digits

```
string s =  "AS_!SD 2453iur ks@d9304-52kasd";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+");

string[] result = matches.Cast<Match>()
                         .Take(2)
                         .Select(match => match.Value)
                         .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result) );
```

will print

```
2453
9304
```

you can parse them to `int[]` by `result.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`

Comment: where i can read more about the regular  expressions?, it seems to be an Amazing tool

Comment: @PachoBeltrán the one and only book on this subject is **Mastering Regular Expressions** by **Jeffrey E.F. Friedl** http://amzn.to/Zfy7jo

Answer (score 0):

You can loop chars of your string parsing them, if you got a exception thats a letter if not is a number them you must to have a list to add this two numbers, and a counter to limitate this.

follow a pseudocode:

```
for char in string:

if counter == 2:
 stop loop

if parse gets exception
 continue

else
 loop again in samestring stating this point
 if parse gets exception
  stop loop
 else add char to list
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the ASCII encoding:

```
string value = "AS_!SD 2453iur ks@d9304-52kasd";

byte zero = 48; // 0
byte nine = 57; // 9

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);

byte[] asciiNumbers = asciiBytes.Where(b => b >= zero && b <= nine)
                    .ToArray();

char[] numbers = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(asciiNumbers);

// OR

string numbersString =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiNumbers);

//First two number from char array
int aNum = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
int bNum =  Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);

//First two number from string
string aString = numbersString.Substring(0,2);
```