# How to take first number from the string in linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I need take first number from the string, for example

```
"12345 this is a number " => "12345"
"123 <br /> this is also numb 2" => "123"
```

etc.

for that I use C# code:

```
    string number = "";
    foreach(char c in ebayOrderId)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            number += c;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;
```

How is it possible to do same via LINQ ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15550651/1283124 but use `Take(1)`

Comment: Sorry, but I need something else

Comment: `"some value 123 <br /> this is also numb 2"` should produce `123` or error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [`Enumerable.TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx):

```
ebayOrderId.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

Comment: +1, better than regular expression

Comment: Note you can shorten this to `ebayOrderId.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)`.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Why is this better than a regex?

Comment: @Joce in the order of importance: readable, shorter, faster.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov That order is quite subjective, but I get your point.

Comment: @Joce sure it's subjective, moreover it's particular to the current situation and my limited awareness about the context and the details. There are plenty of situations, where performance is much-much more demanded than readability. Anyway, I'm glad that you get my point, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) to get the list of digit, then `new string` to get the string number

```
var number = new string(ebayOrderId.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
Regex re=new Regex(@"\d+\w");
```

Try test if this works at http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would improve on @David's answer. `(\d+)[^\d]*`: A number followed by anything that isn't a number.

Your number will be in the first group:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+)[^\d]*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Match m = re.Match("123 <br /> this is also numb 2");

    if (m.Success)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
    }
}
```